# R package: hash: save into R objects on disk very slow

Tags: r, hash

I am using the great `hash` package by Christopher Brown. In my use case, I have several thousand keys in the first level, and each related value may save another 1-3 layers of hash objects. When I try to save it using `save`, it seems to take a really long time.

I then tried `save` and `load` on the exact same setup, except a smaller use case with about 100 keys. The `save` and `load` work well, except it does seem to take longer than doing the same for usual R objects of similar size.

Is this a known problem, and is there any work around of the speed issue?

My machine setup: Mac OSX 10.6, RStudio 0.98.1091, hash 3.0.1.

The code used to generate the data, and the outcome (in comment) is below:

```
library(hash)
library(microbenchmark)

create_hash = function(ahash, level1=10, level2=5, level3=2) {
  for (i in 1:level1) {
    ahash[[paste0('a',i)]] = hash()
    for (j in 1:level2) {
      ahash[[paste0('a',i)]][[paste0('b',j)]] = hash()
      for (k in 1:level3) {
        ahash[[paste0('a',i)]][[paste0('b',j)]][[paste0('c',k)]] = hash()
        ahash[[paste0('a',i)]][[paste0('b',j)]][[paste0('c',k)]][['key1']] = 'value1'
        ahash[[paste0('a',i)]][[paste0('b',j)]][[paste0('c',k)]][['key2']] = 'value2'
      }
    }
  }
}

base1 = hash()
create_hash(base1, 100, 10, 2)
microbenchmark(save(base1, file='base1.Robj'), times=5, unit='s')
# Unit: seconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# save(base1, file = "base1.Robj") 4.962731 4.987589 5.212594 5.102403 5.316056 5.694193     5
# File size: 1.6 MB

base2 = hash()
create_hash(base2, 1000, 10, 2)
microbenchmark(save(base2, file='base2.Robj'), times=5, unit='s')
# Unit: seconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# save(base2, file = "base2.Robj") 108.6682 109.2254 110.4126 109.3526 111.1013 113.7154     5
# File size: 16.1 MB
```

Comment: "seem to take longer" Perceptions may be faulty, so please can you add a reproducible example with some timings (see the `microbenchmark` or `rbenchmark` packages).